# Episerver localizing language for editor UI (content editors)

Tags: episerver

1) Localizing content language(for web site visitors) and localizing editor UI language (for content editors). Are these two implemented differently in Episerver?

There are two ways to localize.

2.1) Xml

What I do not understand is how to get the localized string when there are multiple languages mentioned here?

2.2) Localization service API

This is clear. But can this be used in localizing editor UI language (for content editors)?

The example for #2.1

```
[ContentType(
    Description = "This text can you have in XML instead"
)]
public class StandardPage : PageData
{
        [Display(
            GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content,
            Name = "This text can you have in XML instead ",
            Description = " This text can you have in XML instead " 
        )]
        public virtual ContentArea MainContentArea { get; set; }    
}

<language name="en">
  <contenttypes>
    <standardpage>
      <description>A description of the page type</description>
      <properties>
        <maincontentarea>
          <caption>Name text from XML</caption>
          <help>Description text from XML</help>
        </ maincontentarea >
      </properties>
    </standardpage>
  </contenttypes>
</language>
```

Comment: Consider to split this in to three topics

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking, but:

1. The same localization APIs are used for both the Episerver UI and public-facing websites
2. XML files are *one* of the options for the localization APIs.
3. The XML you posted *would* localize the `MainContentArea` property of the `StandardPage` page type (if placed in an XML language file)